# get empty result from sql query

Tags: sql, select, join

I have this query:

```
select p1.cost as V1, p2.cost as V2 , p3.cost as V3 
from product p1, product p2, product p3 
where p1.id =1 and p2.id =2 and p3.id=3
```

In my product table I have just one row:

```
id   | name       | cost
1    | product1   | 20
```

As you can see here, I ll get empty result !
But how can I do to get:

```
V1   | V2  | V3
20   |     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use left joins:

```
SELECT    p1.cost AS V1, p2.cost AS V2 , p3.cost AS V3 
FROM      product p1
LEFT JOIN product p2 on p2.id = 2
LEFT JOIN product p3 on p3.id = 3
WHERE     p1.id = 1
```

Comment: and maybe `WHERE p1.id = 1`?